# iframe display the curent content website instead of the target of src

Tags: iframe

My iframe code is

```
<iframe src=”http://google.com” width=”400″ height=”600″></iframe>
```

But instead of showing google it show my own website!

You can take a look at http://tetards.ch/node/112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. it was stupid. I use stupid ″ instead of ".